# Domain Driven Design one change per transaction

Tags: domain-driven-design, transaction

Why do they always say you can only change one aggregate per transaction? Decoupling?
Is it a rule you can break or is it more of a strict thing?
Does it also matter if we are in a monolith vs microservices?

Comment: if you need/must to update multiple aggregates in the same transaction, that mean both aggregates can/should be parts of same aggregate. For them being different aggregates, system should support that two aggregates can be in different(no in sync) states

Comment: @Fabio That's correct and I am aware of that. But sometimes you have two different aggregates that need to invoke each other for a business process. That's why you move out of one transaction. But I want to know why it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing multiple aggregates in one transaction introduces constraints in infrastructure - you are tying up the two aggregates to live together in the same bounded context, you need to store them on the same database host, and so on.

This could be viewed as a good practice rather than a rule. You can optimize this based on your product's functionality - will your aggregates always live in the same bounded context? Will they be stored on a single database host? If so, combining the changes makes consistency guarantees so much easier.

But if you are in this situation, I would say the ideal solution is to redesign your aggregate boundaries. Smaller aggregates are almost always better and more focused. Big aggregates can often introduce consistency problems and slower transactions.

One transaction per change (say in a "POST API call") is a basic tenet of good design. One aggregate per transaction further ensures the change does not break invariants.

Some further considerations in favor of one aggregate per transaction:

- Writes are optimized when you stick to the aggregate's transaction boundary because you drastically reduce the chances of deadlocks.
- Most situations where you need to update multiple aggregates can be achieved through eventual consistency. Eventual consistency is guaranteed to be performant. The primary aggregate that is updated first fires a domain event consumed by the second aggregate.
- You are free to refactor the aggregates in the future, even into different bounded contexts.

Comment: Summed it up very well! Thank you @Subhash